# Delete Button SQL Database Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

How can I modify my delete button code to delete a selected row from my SQL database? Currently when I select one row and click the delete button all the rows are deleted.

```
private void delete_button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int selectedIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            string sqlquery;
            string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
            con.Open();
            int rowID = int.Parse(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
            sqlquery = "DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE BookingID = BookingID";

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string CmdString = "SELECT * FROM hotel_booking";
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(CmdString, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is here:`sqlquery = "DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE BookingID = BookingID"`.That where part is always true.

Comment: What can I do to delete only the selected row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try to run this query, it will delete all of your rows

```
DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE BookingID = BookingID
```

`BookingID = BookingID` means it is always true

I think you are trying to use

```
int rowID = int.Parse(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
sqlquery = "DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE BookingID = "+ rowID;
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not acceptable. You MUST use parametrized queries to avoid Sql Injection

Comment: I think there is no possible SQL injection, because you parse index of selected item and it is saved in integer. And numerical index can't be used to inject any Queries, can it ? If I am mistaken, then I am terribly sorry, but please prove me wrong by some facts. @Pikoh

Comment: Maybe in this particular case a SQL Injection is not very likely, but we all must get used to always use parametrized queries. This is even more important when dealing with newbies that doesn't understand when SQL Injection is likely, so we must teach them to use parametrized queries in al cases.

Comment: No problem :), but as @Pikoh said, you should not use this example. In this case it is ok to make the query look like this, but in other cases you should use his solution with parametrized query.

Comment: @RossH yes,it works but be very careful, you should use Parametrized queries. BTW, in my answer there was another typo, that's why it doesn't worked for you.

Comment: What was the other typo?

Comment: @RossH it was in the same line. `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingID", rowID);` in my previous answer `@BookingID` was `@BookingId` ,that is,  `ID` must be capital in both cases

Comment: @RossH try it, as you must get used to that way of querying, but don't change accepted answer. I don't want reputation, I just want you to learn the right way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently deleting all rows because of a mistake in your `WHERE` clause:

```
DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE BookingID = BookingID
```

deletes all rows because in each row `BookingID` equals `BookingID`.

You want to take `rowID` as criteria, so add it as a parameter:

```
int rowID = int.Parse(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
sqlquery = "DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE BookingID = @rid";   
try
{
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
    command.Parameters.Add("@rid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rowID;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

Note that inserting user generated values directly into your query (like `"WHERE BookingID = " + rowID...`) is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com). Although for numeric types this is not such a big danger, you should generally use parameterized queries as above.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
sqlquery = "DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE BookingID = BookingID"
```

That `where` part is always true.

Change it to this:

```
sqlquery = "DELETE FROM hotel_booking WHERE BookingID = @BookingID"
try
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingID", rowID);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ...
```

Comment: It's now saying rowId does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Sorry, a typo. It's `rowID`, so it should be `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingId", rowID);`, i've edited my answer

Comment: Still not working, when I click delete nothing happens at all. But no errors.

Comment: Debug your code and inspect what value of `rowID` is. Maybe is not a value present in the database